# How to make a number wheel loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a random number wheel from 0 to 9. The wheel spins down or up to land on the random number. How can I make it such that the wheel only spins down ? ( Once it reaches 9 the next number is 0, 1, 2... 9, 0, 1, 2) without having to have many divs.

```js
function roll() {
  var randomNum = Number((Math.random() * 100).toFixed(2));
  var firstDigit = Number(Math.floor((randomNum) / 10 - 5));
  var win = firstDigit;
  if (win > 4) {
    var rollm = win * 40 - 40 * 15;
    document.getElementById("roll").style = "margin-top: " + rollm + "px ";
  }
  if (win < 4) {
    var rollm = 180 - 40 * win - 380;
    document.getElementById("roll").style = "margin-top: " + rollm + "px ";
  }
  if (win == 4) {
    var rollm = 360;
    document.getElementById("roll").style = "margin-top: -" + rollm + "px ";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
}
#roll {
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.ticker {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0px 15px 26px;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  transform: translateY(-75px);
}
#roll {
  width: 40px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #0077ee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.roll-h {
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shadow {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(40px);
}
.black,
.his-h {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.black {
  background: black;
}
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="roll-h">
    <div id="roll">
      <div class="black">9</div>
      <div class="black">0</div>
      <div class="black">1</div>
      <div class="black">2</div>
      <div class="black">3</div>
      <div class="black">4</div>
      <div class="black">5</div>
      <div class="black">6</div>
      <div class="black">7</div>
      <div class="black">8</div>
      <div class="black">9</div>
      <div class="black">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ticker"></div>
</div>
<button onClick="roll()" id="spin">Spin</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your snippet a little bit to achieve the behavior you're asking for.

There are two problems though. First, you will need almost twice as many divs to animate the thing properly. Second, the `transitionend` event is [not supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=transitionend), and sometimes it needs to be prefixed, so if you care about supporting things like IE < 10, then it will not work for you out of the box.

### Edit

As sugested in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41659550/2817257) instead of using `transitionend` event you may consider reseting the "wheel" position only when the button is clicked. This is fine but it will require a little more sophisticated implementation because you will need to remember (somehow) which position you need to reset to.

```js
function roll() {
  var win = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  var roll = document.getElementById("roll");
  var onTransitionend = function () {
    roll.classList.remove("animated");
    roll.style = "margin-top: " + (- win * 40) + "px ";
    roll.removeEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionend);
  };
  roll.classList.add("animated");
  roll.style = "margin-top: " + (- win * 40 - 400) + "px ";
  roll.addEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionend);
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
}
#roll.animated {
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.ticker {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0px 15px 26px;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  transform: translateY(-75px);
}
#roll {
  width: 40px;
  // height: 360px;
  background: #0077ee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.roll-h {
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shadow {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(40px);
}
.black,
.his-h {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.black {
  background: black;
}
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="roll-h">
    <div id="roll">
      <div class="black">9</div>
      <div class="black">0</div>
      <div class="black">1</div>
      <div class="black">2</div>
      <div class="black">3</div>
      <div class="black">4</div>
      <div class="black">5</div>
      <div class="black">6</div>
      <div class="black">7</div>
      <div class="black">8</div>
      <div class="black">9</div>
      <div class="black">0</div>
      <div class="black">1</div>
      <div class="black">2</div>
      <div class="black">3</div>
      <div class="black">4</div>
      <div class="black">5</div>
      <div class="black">6</div>
      <div class="black">7</div>
      <div class="black">8</div>
      <div class="black">9</div>
      <div class="black">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ticker"></div>
</div>
<button onClick="roll()" id="spin">Spin</button>
```

Comment: is it possible to make it roll past 1-9 at least once before slowing down? for example, if the number is 1, it will just roll from 0 to 1, can it be , 0,1...9,0,1(stop).

Comment: Sure, you just need to add more divs and make sure you choose the right shift when you start the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

One solution you could do is shift all of the divs to the top each time the button is pressed, so that it always needs to scroll down to get the the next number. Here is a more modular way of doing it:

```js
document.getElementById('spin').onclick = makeSpinner('roll', function(num) {
  // handle new number here
  console.log(num);
});

function makeSpinner(id, callback) {
  
  /* Initialization */
  var rollDiv = document.getElementById(id);
  var currentNum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
    rollDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  }
  resetSpinner(9);
  
  /* Helper Functions */
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    // min inclusive, max inclusive
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  function resetSpinner(startNum) {
    rollDiv.classList.remove('animatedSpinner');
    rollDiv.style.marginTop = "0px";
    rollDiv.scrollTop = 0;
    rollDiv.classList.add('animatedSpinner');
    for (var node = rollDiv.firstElementChild, num = startNum;
         node !== null;
         node = node.nextElementSibling, num = (num + 1) % 10) {
      node.innerText = num;
    }
  }
  
  /* Main Function */
  return function () {
    var previous = (currentNum + 9) % 10;
    var distanceRolled = getRandomInt(1, 10) + 10;
    currentNum = (currentNum + distanceRolled) % 10;
    resetSpinner(previous);
    rollDiv.style.marginTop = -40 * distanceRolled + "px";
    typeof callback === 'function' && callback(currentNum);
  };
}
```

```css
#roll {
  color: #fff;
  width: 40px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #0077ee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.animatedSpinner {
  transition: 1s ease;
}
#roll > div {
  background: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.ticker {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 0px 15px 26px;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  transform: translateY(-75px);
}
.roll-h {
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 60px !important;  
}
```

```html
<div style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block">
  <div class="roll-h">
    <div id="roll"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ticker"></div>
</div>
<button id="spin">Spin</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var p = document.getElementById("cont");
var max = 9; //max element in meter
//create items
for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++)
{
  var child = document.createElement("div");
  child.innerHTML = i;
  child.style.top = (i * 30) + "px";
  child.setAttribute('id', i);
  p.appendChild(child);

}
//add listeners to buttons
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', spin);
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', stopSpin);
//set up interval id so that in future timer can be stopped
var intervalId=null,randomNum=null;
//spin function
function spin() 
{
 randomNum=null;
  intervalId=setInterval(function() 
  {
    var temp = 0;
    //decrease top value of each item by 5px; can by any number to make fast or slow
    for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++) 
    {
      var item = document.getElementById("" + i); //get item by its id 0-max
      var itemTop = (parseInt(item.style.top)); //get item top in integer
      item.style.top = (itemTop - 5) + "px"; //update top value
      itemTop = (parseInt(item.style.top));//get updated value
      if (itemTop < -30) //place element at last if below -30px
      {
        item.style.top = ((max - temp) * 30) + "px";
        temp++;
      }
      //check if stopped button was pressed
      if(itemTop==60&&randomNum==parseInt(item.innerHTML)) // pointer shows number at 60px
      {
       //stop meter
       clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }
  }, 20);
}

function stopSpin()
{
 //just generate randome number at which meter should stop
  randomNum=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+0);
 console.log(randomNum)  
  
}
```

```css
#pointer {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 194px;
  top: 63px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#cont {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 30px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}

#cont>div {
  backgroud: black;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
</div>
<div id="pointer">
</div>
<button id='start'>start</button>
<button id='stop'>stop</button>
```

Checkout this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fx0vdkay/)

Main point is to place the previous element to the last

Little bit late but i hope this will help you.